# updateall check if succeeded worked or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using a update_all to update info in DB

Firstly my SQL look like this.

```
UPDATE "users" SET "tag" = 'D', "fencing_token" = 199,  WHERE "user"."id" = $1 AND (fencing_token < 199)  [["id", 143]]
```

Notice the where clause `fencing_token`

Now my `update_all` look like this

```
User.where(id: 143).where('fencing_token < ?',199).update_all({tag: 'D',fencing_token: 199})
```

Is there a way to know whether or not the following SQL query affected the row.

I see `update_all` return `true/false` as the output of the execution.

Question?

Can I consider that return value to understand the query has affected the row (if true) else not.

Comment: Are you running it directly on production?

Comment: Maybe you can test out on development environment first.

Answer (score 0):

**(If you are not running the query on production directly)**

Check if you find any record with `fencing_token < 199` as follows:

```
User.where(id: 143).where('fencing_token < ?',199)
```

You should get no records.

Comment: that where clause is there for a purpose that fencing token is used to avoid race condition(in distributed processing) for any insert/update happening in parallel at the same time. Example there could be a `update running` which set `fencing token` as `200` so ideally the above query i.e `199`  should not affect the row because `200` is more closer and more realtime than `199`

Comment: The point is to query only onces time instead of find it first and updating it causing a potential race conditions to happen and resulting in stale value in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Running update_all on an ActiveRecord::Relation object will return the number of rows (integer) affected by the UPDATE. Therefore if you expect one query result and the output of update_all is 1, you can consider the record as being affected.

I don't know your application but if the User id is unique to that user record its more conventional in Rails to retrieve it by doing User.find(143) and then using the update method instead of update all since you would only be updating a single record.

Comment: `I don't know your application but if the User id is unique to that user record its more conventional in Rails to retrieve it by doing User.find(143)` Check the comment I made to @SakshiJain answer. Also do you have a reference for it anywhere in Rails doc where it say the return values are number of record updated or row affected.

Comment: I dont think its included in the rails doc, but if you follow the rails source code in ActiveRecord ultimately, update_all calls an update statement with a comment that explains the return value [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb). (line 131)